# Checkpoints in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Hi I am very new to HBase and I am unable to understand the concept of checkpoints in HBase. I want to know what are the checkpoints in HBase and how can we configure or use them?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments I think you want to know about snapshot.Let me clear you here that checkpoint is just backing up and snapshot is just same typo scenario . Plese read the attachments given in the link so you can get a good overview of snapshot.
[Snapshot pdf's](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-50/)

Answer (score 0):

by checkpoint do you mean snapshot??if yes then then go ahead...a snapshot of hbase takes a copy of the specified table at a particular point in time.it can be used as a backup of the current table...a snapshot can be created by the hbaseadmin only..also if one snapshot of a table is ongoing, other snapshot requests for the same table should not be permitted..during the creation of a snapshot, the table could continue to take on reads and writes.

Comment: thanx :) but how can i do take this snapshot? or in other words create my backup?

Comment: The state of an Hbase table comprises of the memstore content of all currently running region servers and the content of the /hbase/tablename directory in HDFS...and metadata which mainly is the current state of the schema and region information, is kept in .META. catalog table.To create a snapshot of a table, all these information should be backed up into the directory /hbase/.snapshot/, where each snapshot is further kept under a sub-directory "snapshotname".

Comment: but how can I create snapshot - i mean import and export the tables?

Comment: you can use the Export and Import classes provided by the Hbase Snapshot API..you can visit this link for the documentation - http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html